# Jersey: Injecting of shared object not working with Jetty

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0

We want to implement a REST-Service on a Jetty, that receives a Heartbeat from multiple Clients and these Heartbeats are stored in a Hashmap to work with them in further functionallities.

Thats how the code looks like at the moment:

The class that should be injected.

```
public class SharedMemory {

    private SharedMemory sharedMemory = null;
    private HashMap<String, HeartbeatModel> memory = null;
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock  = lock.readLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

    public SharedMemory(){
        memory = new HashMap<String, HeartbeatModel>();
    }

    ...
}
```

The binder class:

```
public class SharedMemoryBinder extends AbstractBinder{
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(new SharedMemory()).to(SharedMemory.class);
    }
}
```

The feature class:

```
public class SharedMemoryFeature implements Feature{
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new SharedMemoryBinder());
        return true;
     }
}
```

The service class

```
@Path("/HeartbeatService")
public class GCEHeartbeatService {

    @Inject
    private SharedMemory sharedMemory;

    @POST
    @Path("/postHeartbeat")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postHeartbeat(Heartbeat heartbeat){
        sharedMemory.storeToMemory(heartbeat);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
    ...
}
```

The application class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(GCEHeartbeatService.class);
        classes.add(SharedMemoryFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

These are the used dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.hszg</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So with this configuration, i always get a 415 unsupported media type exception when i post a heartbeat to the postHeartbeat service, even with another media type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...i always get a 415 unsupported media type exception when i post"

This doesn't seem like a problem related to your DI configuration. It looks like you just need to register the JSON provider. With this particular provider

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If you override the registration of resources/provider through classpath scanning (which you have done, simply by overriding `getClasses()` and returning a non-empty set, then the provider will not be registered.

You can simply register it yourself.

```
classes.add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
-- or --
classes.add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
```

If you look in the jar, you will also see an `ExceptionMapper` you may want to register.

Alternatively, you can use [this dependency](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

which wraps the above dependency in a auto-discoverable feature, and registers, the provider and the `ExceptionMapper`. With this dependency, you won't need to register anything. If for some weird reason it isn't register, you can just add it yourself

```
classes.add(JacksonFeature.class);
```

---

As an aside, if portability is not an issue, I would use the `ResourceConfig` class (which extends `Application`) instead. It's much easier to work with.

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        packages("scan.packages.for.resource.and.provider");
        register(ResourceOrProvider.class);
        register(new MyAppBinder());
    }
}
```

See the [`ResourceConfig` API](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, the missing class for the jacksonprovider was the problem in this case. I was not aware of the impact of the overridden getClass function. So it works fine now. I will check your suggestions.